# Unable to Remove Decimal value from price in Magento, After made Changes in all possible core files

Tags: php, magento, decimal

I have read many blogs related "How To Remove Decimal From Magento Prices".
But they are still not working for my website.

I have followed the link - "[How To Remove Decimal From Magento-1 Prices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288819/how-to-remove-decimal-from-magento-prices) " 
And made the changes according to that, Also
Made changes in some files listed below that are instructed in the solution link-

1) At the root folder "js/varien/js.js"

2) app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php

3) app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php

4) app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php

5) lib/Zend/Currency.php

After that I have clear **cache** also

If anyone has any other solution, Kindly help me.

Comment: have you `rebuild indexes` and re-run the `compilation process`??

Comment: Yeah, I had rebuilt indexes before.  But Compilation Process worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For complete this go to here: app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php

```
 and replace this put 0 place on 2 on in this function:

public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer =     true, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
} 

then refresh.....
```

Comment: Thanks, But I already changed "app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php" file as I mentioned in question at Point Number 2.